# How to show modal using controller? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my code

view

```
<div class="modal fade"id="myModal2" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

     <h4 class="modal-title">Declare New Property?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body Content">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to create controller because my side bar has default href in controller.

Comment: not much clear ur requirement pls add more details

Comment: Btw, modal is in applicant_header.php under view.

Comment: I just wanna call myModal2 in controller. Is that possible?

Comment: and where in controller? add some code what u have tried so far?

Comment: I am assuming "calling" myModal2, is to fire up the modal?

Comment: and controller is show_modal. I don't know how to start the code. I did research but i didnt find anything. i just wanna fire up the modal when i call the show_modal controller

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "call"/fireup myModal2 via a Codeigniter's Controller. A Controller in CI is simply a class named in a way which can be associated with the URI, with each of its methods an entry point to a page. Clicking on the "href" redirects your browser to the URI, it does not and will not fire the modal as you have expected.

You will need javascript/jQuery to fire up a modal.  I am assuming the above HTML and the menu HTML is stored in a **Codeigniter view file**, loaded by the controller and also that you are using **Bootstrap Modal**. The following are 2 ways to go about firing modal in jQuery(remember to load jQuery).

**#1 Clicking the link (show_modal) to fire up the modal**

```
<!-- assuming the link html in menu, the same link you wrote to redirect users to the controller method-->
<a id='the-link-id'>Fire Modal</a>    

<!-- jQuery code to fire modal-->
$(function(){
   $(document).on(".click","#the-link-id",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#myModal2").modal('toggle');
   });
})
```

**#2 Redirecting users to controller method (show_mdal) which loads the view file containing the modal and fire it when the view is loaded.**

```
<!-- jQuery code to fire modal when the view file is loaded-->
$(function(){
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myModal2").modal('toggle');
   });
})
```

IMHO, the second way seems much like what you want; but it's weird from the UX perspective.

I hope this helps.